# Unix - Automated MD5SUM Verification / Security reccommendations

Tags: security, unix, ssl, shell-script

This is my first post on here so go easy on me!

I am currently looking into ways of securing a number of E-Commerce websites which serve a large amount of tragic each day.

So far we have implemented WAF's (Web Application Firewall), SSL Certificates, Malware detection (using a range of different softwares) and also made changes to the E-Commerce software which will make breaching the site harder (Changing admin urls etc).

An idea was given to me by a co-worker which would be to check the MD5Sum of each and every file within the E-Commerce software. My Question is; Is this something which is achievable/worth doing and if so, how would i go about MD5Summing 10k+ files on each site?

I am open to any suggestions you may have, i will also post this on the security board too.

Thanks for your time.
Lewis

Comment: If you’re worried about attackers changing files, just mount the filesystem read-only. Keep in mind though that some (cache) folders may need to be writable.

Comment: This is not possible for a number of reasons, A: cache folders are required for massive performance gains which are always being updated.

B: New products/information are always being updated so locally stored images are frequently uploaded.

C: The sites are oftenly having additional work being added (development work)

I appreciate the suggestion though!

Comment: @LewisBrowne - Why would you not simply exclude cache directories?

Comment: Not an answer, but use Sha512 over md5 sums. Both are good and logically similar but md5 sums are more about data integrity for downloads (less cpu) while Sha sums are harder to create a collision for.  Checksumming those files will require a fair amount of disk io, which could become an issue.

Comment: Also, you have not advised the architecture, but jailing each website can prevent cross-infection in some cases - (for php for example)  eg using  open_basedir and disable_functions to limit scope and access of malicious scripts.  Also add monitoring to detect and block brute Force attacks (eg fail2ban with custom rules or plugin/module).  Disable - as much as possible - signatures of the software being sent.